# Pig Scripting with sum functions

Tags: apache-pig

My input file is below

```
a,t1,1000,100
a,t1,2000,200
a,t1,1000,500
b,t2,1000,200
b,t2,5000,100
```

This is my script. It is throwing sum error. Could you please correct it

```
myinput      = LOAD 'file' USING PigStorage(',') AS(a1:chararray,a2:chararray,total:int,div:int)
for_disticnt = FOREACH myinput GENERATE a2;
grp_disticnt = GROUP for_distinct ALL;
disticnt_count=FOREACH grp_disticnt GENEARATE COUNT(for_disticnt) as finalcount;
grouped = GROUP myinput BY a1;
result = FOREACH grouped GENEARTE group,SUM(myinput.total/myinput.div)/distinct_count;
```

so the output of grouped is

```
 ((a),{(a,t1,1000,100),(a,t1,2000,200)})

 ((b),{(b,t2,1000,200),(b,t2,5000,100)})
```

I would like to divide $2 by $3 in each tuple  of bag for a single group and then do the SUM of it and then finally divide that SUM by  distinct $1.

The sum logic is below for each bag in grouped.

```
[(1000/100)+((2000/200)]/count(distinct $1 in myinput) 

[(1000/200)+(5000/100)]/count(distinct $1 in myinput)
```

I want output as below

```
(a,10)
(b,27)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myinput = load 'data' using PigStorage(',') as 
          (a1:chararray, a2:chararray, total:int, div:int);

sub = foreach myinput generate a2;
dist = DISTINCT sub;
grpd = group dist all;
X = foreach grpd generate COUNT_STAR(dist);

A = foreach myinput generate a1, (total / div) as quotient;
grouped = group A by a1;
B = foreach grouped generate group, SUM(A.quotient) as sums;
C = CROSS B, X;
final = foreach C generate $0, ((float)($1) / (float)($2));
```

**Output**

```
(a,11.0)
(b,27.5)
```

Comment: No. I would like to divide total and div in each tuple and find the sum of all results of divisions in each tuple.

Comment: I guess I am confused by your desired output.  I'm not sure how `[(1000/200)+(5000/100)]/count(distinct $1 in myinput)` gets you `5`

Comment: At any rate, I edited my answer to what I think you are asking for but still not sure how you got `5` for the second calculation.

Comment: yes. My bad mistake at second calculation.. I will try this answer that you posted..

Comment: but distinct_count will give 2 . but if I change the input file as above then it is giving distinct count.Please help. I need the final division by distinct $1 in myinput.

Comment: as per script above the distinct_count simply give total count. I need the final division by distinct count

Comment: :) Okay I finally understand what you are getting at.  I edited it.  I think this is correct.